# Способ вызов функции в JS (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Объясните пожалуйста разницу может вызовами функций `_checkTitle() { blah }` и `_checkTitle = () => { blah }`, будут вызывать из компонента `<button onPress={this._checkTitle} />`
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Не-стрелочная функция - способ задания функции в es5 и более ранних стандартах js

```
function _checkTitle() {
  console.log('blah');
}
```

Стрелочная функция - способ задания функции, который можно использовать в es6 стандарте наравне с не-стрелочным способом.

```
_checkTitle = () => {
  console.log('blah');
}
```

Оба вышеприведенных способа делают одно и тоже. Но, есть некоторые нюансы связанные с тем, что у стрелочной функции нет собственного this, т.е. внутри стрелочной функции this наследуется из лексического окружения, что отличается от не-стрелочной функции, у которой this определяется контекстом вызова.